# Calculating Cross Correlation for 1D Signals in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, signals, correlation

Can someone help me out in doing the cross correlation for 1D signals in C/C++, using libraries such as Intel MKL or FFTW3 or Armadillo or GNU-GSL etc. I am using Ubuntu 18 64 Bit.

Tried a lot of combinations, either library is not getting integrated properly, or it is just calculating the correlation coefficient not the correlation value between the data provided (happening with GSL), my data is huge in numbers, in float, around 30k of listing.

Please help me out with a code logic to work out with these libraries.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <forkjoin.h>
    #include <shared.h>
    #include <barrier.h>
    int main()
   {
   int *a,*b,pid,nproc,i,*bar,sum1,sum2,size;
   int shmid1,shmid2,shmid3,shmid4,shmid5,shmid6,shmid7,shmid8;
   float *a1,*b1,*ab,*mean1,*mean2,total; 

   printf("Enter the size of the array : ");
   scanf("%d",&size);
   a = (int *) create_memory(2*size,&shmid1);
   b = (int *) create_memory(2*size,&shmid2);
   a1 = (float *) create_memory(4*size,&shmid4);
   b1 = (float *) create_memory(4*size,&shmid5);
   ab = (float *) create_memory(4*size,&shmid6);
   mean1 = (float *) create_memory(4,&shmid7);
   mean2 = (float *) create_memory(4,&shmid8);
   bar = (int *) create_memory(2*4,&shmid3);

   for(i=0;i<size;i++)        
   {
         printf("Enter %d Element of x : ",i+1);
         scanf("%d",&a[i]);
         printf("Enter %d Element of y : ",i+1);
         scanf("%d",&b[i]);  
   }
   printf("Enter the no of process : ");
   scanf("%d",&nproc);
   barrier_init(bar,nproc);
   sum1=0;
   sum2=0;
   pid=create_process(&nproc);
   for(i=pid;i<size;i+=nproc)
   {
         sum1 = sum1 + a[i];
         sum2 = sum2 + b[i];
   } 
   barrier(bar);

   (*mean1) += (float)sum1/size;
   (*mean2) += (float)sum2/size;

   barrier(bar);
   for(i=pid;i<size;i+=nproc)
   {    
         a1[i] = (a[i])-(*mean1);
         b1[i] = (b[i])-(*mean2);
   }
   for(i=pid;i<size;i+=nproc)
   {    
         ab[i] = a1[i]*b1[i];
   }
   join_process(&nproc,&pid);
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
         total = total+ab[i];
   } 
   printf("The Correlation is : %f \n",total);
   if(total >= 0)
         printf("The Correlation  is Positive\n"); 
   else  
         printf("The Correlation is Negative \n");
   cleanup_memory(&shmid1);
   cleanup_memory(&shmid2);
   cleanup_memory(&shmid3);
   cleanup_memory(&shmid4);
   cleanup_memory(&shmid5);
   cleanup_memory(&shmid6);
   cleanup_memory(&shmid7);
   cleanup_memory(&shmid8);
   return 0;              

   }
```

here the header files such as Forkjoin and barrier are not able to be located.

Thanks
Abhinav

Comment: Please show your code and ask a concrete question. Asking to write code for you is not how this site works.

Comment: Please show your source and your library

Comment: I have edit the question, with the code, please check

Comment: regarding Cross-Correlation in MKL - my recommendation you to try a similar functionality from the Intel IPP library.  Please check the ippiCrossCorrNorm_*.* function. the reason why I don't recommend you to use MKL in this case --  this functionality is not well optimized. the examples of this code you may find out into IPP Forum -  https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-integrated-performance-primitives/